# Execute JS code after pressing the spacebar

Tags: javascript, keyup

this is my code in JavaScript:

```
var changeIdValue =  function(id, value) {
document.getElementById(id).style.height = value;
};

document.getElementById ("balklongwaarde").addEventListener("click", function(){ changeIdValue("balklongwaarde", "60px")});

document.getElementById ("balklevensverwachting").addEventListener("click", function(){ changeIdValue("balklevensverwachting", "60px")});

document.getElementById ("balkhart").addEventListener("click", function(){ changeIdValue("balkhart", "60px")});

document.getElementById ("balklever").addEventListener("click", function(){ changeIdValue("balklever", "60px")});

document.getElementById("balkhersenen").addEventListener("click", function(){ changeIdValue("balkhersenen", "60px")});
```

I want to execute this code after press on keyup....

Has anyone an idea how?

Comment: On keyup for which? Any of those elements?

Comment: This may be of great use, it was for me. http://dmauro.github.io/Keypress/

Answer (score 128, accepted):

There're couple of ways to do this. I am also including a deprecated one with `keyCode` (from the original answer) just in case (it still seems to work actually as of 2023).

```
document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.key == " " ||
      e.code == "Space" ||      
      e.keyCode == 32      
  ) {
    //your code
  }
}
```

**BONUS**: I've made a quick snippet to get `key`, `code` and `keyCode` for any character.

Usage: 1) type in any letter 2) profit!

*Pro tip*: you could also run a snippet in different browsers to have fallbacks just in case.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><input type="text" placeholder="enter a char here" id="char-finder"><p class="key"> <pr>key</pr> for <pr class="char">space</pr> is <pr class="tr">&nbsp;</pr></p><p class="code"> <pr>code</pr> for <pr class="char">space</pr> is <pr class="tr">Space</pr></p><p class="keycode"> <pr>keyCode</pr> for <pr class="char">space</pr> is <pr class="tr">32</pr></p><script>document.getElementById('char-finder').onkeyup=function(e){key=e.key==" " ? "&nbsp;" : e.key; code=e.code; kcode=e.keyCode; char=e.key==" " ? "space" : e.key; $(".key .tr").html(key); $(".code .tr").html(code); $(".keycode .tr").html(kcode); $(".char").html(char);}</script><style>body{font-size: 17px;}input{border: 1px solid grey; border-radius: 10px; font-size: 15px; padding: 5px;}pr{font-family: Menlo; padding: 3px; border-radius: 5px; font-size: 15px; display: inline-flex; justify-content: center; background: rgb(230, 230, 230); min-width: 20px;}.key pr:first-child{background: rgb(0, 230, 230);}.keycode pr:first-child{background: rgb(230, 0, 50); color: white;}.code pr:first-child{background: rgb(230, 230, 0);}pr.tr{margin-left: 5px; border: 1px solid black; background:transparent;}</style>
```

Comment: Apparently `keyCode` [is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress). It might be better to use: `if (e.keyCode === 32 || e.key === ' ')`

Comment: in iOS it's fine , its not working in android mobile web browsers

Comment: @z0r seems that IE doesn't recognize `e.key === ' '` but `e.key === 'Spacebar'`

Answer (score 32):

The 2019 version of this would be: (works in all major browsers - Chrome, Firefox, Safari)

Spec link - https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#dom-keyboardevent-code

> **code** holds a string that identifies the physical key being pressed. The value is not affected by the current keyboard layout or modifier state, so a particular key will always return the same value.
>   The un-initialized value of this attribute MUST be "" (the empty string).

```js
// event = keyup or keydown
document.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
  if (event.code === 'Space') {
    console.log('Space pressed')
  }
})
```

Answer (score 11):

In JQuery events are normalised under [which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) event property.

You can find any key value here **eg:spacebar value(32)**.

This function may help you.

```
$(window).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 32) {

        //Your code goes here

    }
});
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you

Answer (score 7):

[`keyCode` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode). You could use `key` (the character generated by pressing the key) or `code` (physical key on the keyboard) instead. Using one or another can have different outputs depending on the keyboard layout.

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if (e.code === "Space") {
        // Do your thing
    }
});
```

or

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => 
    if (e.key === " ") {
        // Do your thing
    }
});
```

Comment: You're right I made a typo, I edited the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

`document.activeElement` is whatever element has focus. You'll often find both spacebar and enter firing click on the focused element.

```
document.body.onkeyup = function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 32 || e.keyCode == 13){
        //spacebar or enter clicks focused element
        try {
            doc.activeElement.click();
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }            
    }
};
```

Then the CSS might be:

```
.focusable-thing:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.focusable-thing:focus {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

Comment: can anyone tell me what is `onkeyup` on `document.body.onkeyup`  . What does it mean and why it is used