# How to prevent to enter space/whitespace in password input field | ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

Here I provide my code where I want to enter characters into the password input field and I want to do not enter whitespace/space in it but it also going inside of it instead when I print input value then it does not contain space/whitespace. Please help me to resolve the issue.

[CodeSandBox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/x92844rjqq)

Code -

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";
import { Form, Input, Label } from "semantic-ui-react";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inputFieldData: {
        pass: {
          val: "",
          error: false
        }
      }
    };
  }

  inputChange = e => {
    // prevent not to enter space charactes in password field while registering
    const re = /^\S*$/;
    let inputFieldData = this.state.inputFieldData;
    const name = e.target.name;
    if (re.test(e.target.value)) {
      inputFieldData[name]["val"] = e.target.value;
      console.log(e.target.value);
    }
    this.setState({ inputFieldData });
  };

  render() {
    const { inputFieldData } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Input box does not contain space in it</h1>
        <h3>Input Value: {inputFieldData["pass"]["val"]}</h3>
        <Form className="register-form">
          <Form.Field>
            <Input
              type="password"
              icon="user circle"
              name="pass"
              iconPosition="left"
              placeholder="Enter Password"
              onChange={this.inputChange}
              error={inputFieldData["pass"]["error"]}
            />
            {inputFieldData["pass"]["error"] && (
              <Label basic color="red" pointing>
                Field can not be empty
              </Label>
            )}
          </Form.Field>
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: let's users type their password. Then, you can `trim(password)` before you call the API

Comment: You could simply detect a spacebar, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386354/execute-js-code-after-pressing-the-spacebar)

Comment: I know, but I do not want to use `trim()`. I want to do not enter space character inside the input box. @VuLuu

Comment: I tried your method before I posted this question but it didn't help me. @TusharWalzade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the value of the input to `inputFieldData.pass.val`,
otherwise it is [not bound to the state of your component](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html).

```
        <Input
          value={inputFieldData.pass.val}
          type="password"
          icon="user circle"
          name="pass"
          iconPosition="left"
          placeholder="Enter Password"
          onChange={this.inputChange}
          error={inputFieldData["pass"]["error"]}
        />
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the controlled component pattern (see here https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) by adding the `value` prop to your `input` component.

You can then add the space trimming logic in your `handleChange` function.

Here is an example : https://codesandbox.io/s/kkpr53k36r

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem with regex

```
str.replace(/\s/g, '')
```

Comment: It works partially, but he also have to set the value to the input fields as without value component works as uncontrolled one and it will have its own state.

Answer (score -1):

Simply do like this in handleOnChange Function:

```
 handleOnChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value.split(" ").join("")
    });
  };
```