# Keyboard Performing Differently on Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, responsive

I have a keyboard created in html and designed to be responsive. The keyboard looks and works correctly on desktop, but is cut off and looks completely different in mobile browsers. On mobile the color and shape of buttons is different, and the "delete" and "q" buttons are cut off with no option to scroll. Examples of the keyboard on both types of browsers and a snippet are below.

index.html

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  float: center;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  object-fit: scale-down;
}

#game-board {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.letter-box {
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 2px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.filled-box {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.letter-row {
  display: flex;
}

#keyboard-cont-cont {
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: visible;
}

#keyboard-cont {
  margin: 1rem 0;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  padding: 0vw 40vw;
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: solid lightGray;
  font-family: monospace;
  --e: calc(100vw / 35);
}

#keyboard-cont div {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
}

.center {
  width: 50%;
}

.second-row {
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
  margin: calc(var(--e) / 2);
  position: relative;
}

.keyboard-button {
  font-size: var(--e);
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: calc(var(--e) / 2);
  margin: 0 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.center {
  width: 50%;
}

.first-row {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}

.second-row {
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}

.third-row {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}

.keyboard-button {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin: 0 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

/* Style the header links */
.header a {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.header button {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
/* Style the logo link (notice that we set the same value of line-height and font-size to prevent the header to increase when the font gets bigger */
.header v.logo {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* Change the background color on mouse-over */
.header button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Style the active/current link*/
.header button.active {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
}

/* Float the link section to the right */
.header-right {
  float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  .keyboard-button{
     font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0.1rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="keyboard-cont-cont">
      <div id="keyboard-cont">
          <div class="first-row">
              <button class="keyboard-button">q</button>
              <button class="keyboard-button">w</button>
              <button class="keyboard-button">e</button>
              <button class="keyboard-button">r</button>
              <button class="keyboard-button">t</button>
              <button class="keyboard-button">y</button>
              <button class="keyboard-button">u</button>
              <button class="keyboard-button">i</button>
              <button class="keyboard-button">o</button>
              <button class="keyboard-button">p</button>
          </div>
          <div class="second-row">
              <button class="keyboard-button">a</button>
              <button class="keyboard-button">s</button>
              <button class="keyboard-button">d</button>
              <button class="keyboard-button">f</button>
              <button class="keyboard-button">g</button>
              <button class="keyboard-button">h</button>
              <button class="keyboard-button">j</button>
              <button class="keyboard-button">k</button>
              <button class="keyboard-button">l</button>
          </div>
          <div class="third-row">
              <button class="keyboard-button">Del</button>
              <button class="keyboard-button">z</button>
              <button class="keyboard-button">x</button>
              <button class="keyboard-button">c</button>
              <button class="keyboard-button">v</button>
              <button class="keyboard-button">b</button>
              <button class="keyboard-button">n</button>
              <button class="keyboard-button">m</button>
              <button class="keyboard-button">Enter</button>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Mobile Keyboard
[image: Mobile]

Desktop Keyboard

[image: desktop]

Comment: just curious, what's the point of reinventing the wheel? xD

Comment: I'm working through a wordle clone type of game to mess around with, and I need to be able to change attributes of the keyboard as the game progresses. If there's a better way I'm all ears

Comment: what do you mean by attributes of the keyboard? js allows you to bind any action to a click on an actual keyboard key, see example of how this binding works: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24386354

Comment: Yeah, I'm binding the keys to their inputs in my JS, but the issue I'm having is with the display itself. The attributes I'm talking about are enabling/disabling keys, coloring different letters at different times, etc.

Comment: At one point in the CSS you set font size in relation to viewport width which seems the sensible thing to do. But this is overridden with setting in relation to rem. rem has no relation to viewport width so there is no guarantee it will fit. Could you describe why this change was made?